# Семантичная разметка на странице

Tags: html, семантика

Делаю сейчас дизайн для сайта и никак не могу определиться с нужными тегами

```html
<section class="articles">
  <article>
    <header><!--Заголовок и вспомогательная информация ввиде даты публикации и просмотров--></header>
    <div><!--Картинка публикации и текст публикации--></div>
    <footer><!--Теги, ссылки--></footer>
  </article>
  <!--... и так далее -->
</section>
```

Меня в данной ситуации смущает тег div - т.к он ассемантичен. Что подставить вместо него не понимаю. Нужна помощь!

Comment: либо без дива вовсе, либо section можете добавить. http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/ - тут примеры есть

Comment: @nueq без дива неудобно т.к теряется гибкость содержимого (я не могу позиционировать его)

Comment: А внутри дива img и p не вариант?

Comment: @SultanovShamil я же говорю что это не семантично! Вы чем читаете?

Comment: @SultanovShamil, там сам div не совсем семантичен (html5)

Comment: @MaximPro, вот еще пример от товарищей из mozilla - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article, так же юзают section в article

Comment: @nueq варианты приведенные в той статье несколько странные.
Есть вариант с хедером и футером, но в середине все открыто (незапаковано в тег)...после этого примеры совсем какие-то специфичные (ну по крайней мере для меня)
P.S Это про хтмл доктора.
Про мозиллу похожий случай, нашпиговали все в кучу и вышло как у доктора: куча sectionов...зачем не понятно. Самое главное я не видел примера с хедером, секшионом и футером

Comment: @MaximPro, на сколько я понимаю. если сам article - прост, можно не создавать div, section и т.д., на мозиле такая же разметка есть

Comment: @nueq у меня несколько сложная разметка мне нужен и хэдер и футер и основная запакованная в теги часть тоже нужна. Но семантично ли это будет если я напишу section вместо моего текущего div?
P.S Я смотрел разметку вордпресс блогов и там 2 лагеря: либо на все забивается и все усыпается дивами, либо есть article с header открытым телом и footer

Comment: @MaximPro, почему нет?) MDN для Вас не показатель?)

Comment: @nueq а что MDN?

Answer (score 1):

Если на месте дива будет только текст и изображения, то див ставить и не нужно. Можно сделать так как предлагают сами [W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/article):

```
<article>
  <header>
   <h1>The Very First Rule of Life</h1>
   <p><time pubdate datetime="2009-10-09T14:28-08:00"></time></p>
  </header>
  <p>If there's a microphone anywhere near you, assume it's hot and
  sending whatever you're saying to the world. Seriously.</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <footer>
   <a href="?comments=1">Show comments...</a>
  </footer>
</article>
```

Если есть другие элементы, также можно подсмотреть в спецификации. `Article` может быть внутри `article`, так же можно использовать `section`:

```
<article>
 <header>
  <h1>The Very First Rule of Life</h1>
  <p><time pubdate datetime="2009-10-09T14:28-08:00"></time></p>
 </header>
 <p>If there's a microphone anywhere near you, assume it's hot and
 sending whatever you're saying to the world. Seriously.</p>
 <p>...</p>
 <section>
  <h1>Comments</h1>
  <article>
   <footer>
    <p>Posted by: George Washington</p>
    <p><time pubdate datetime="2009-10-10T19:10-08:00"></time></p>
   </footer>
   <p>Yeah! Especially when talking about your lobbyist friends!</p>
  </article>
  <article>
   <footer>
    <p>Posted by: George Hammond</p>
    <p><time pubdate datetime="2009-10-10T19:15-08:00"></time></p>
   </footer>
   <p>Hey, you have the same first name as me.</p>
  </article>
 </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Как я писал в комментариях неудобно потом позиционировать содержимое дива если дива нет.

Comment: используйте section вместо div

Comment: А что думаете насчет article внутри article? По сути я хочу обернуть картинку с текстом. А как гласит правило тег article используется когда содержимое самодостаточно. То есть выходит я могу легко использовать article вместо div

Comment: Я думаю, что вполне можете, ведь такой вариант предлагает сам w3c

Comment: И еще я правильно понимаю смысл section? Он используется для группировки связанного между собой контента? Выходит текст и картинка связаны между собой?

Comment: Исходя из официальной документации : https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/article - section - представляет родительский элемент контента, а article - независимый элемент section.

Comment: Так там же в вики и написано что он служит для группировки связанного между собой контента или я не прав?